# Installing gcc without admin?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

Is there a place to install command line programs on OSX without an admin password? I've tried /bin and /usr/bin, and I have permission for neither. Like a ~/Applications, but for the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apps can run from anywhere, so if you don't want to authenticate as an admin user, you'll want to write it to /Users/Shared or ~ and expand your path to accommodate wherever you chose to land the package.

If you're working in a lab situation, you can make a USB drive called dev and a folder named bin to contain gcc would require something like this for the default bash shell:

```
export PATH=/Volumes/dev/bin:$PATH
```